# Enrich a featurecollection with more data

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, elevation, feature-collection

I have generated a vector feature collection which is great but I would like to add to this data before saving it out as a CSV. So the data is areas of forest loss in the county of Gwent and I want to add extra fields like average, min and max elevation to each polygon.

How would I do that before I save out the CSV?

```
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM2_NAME', ['Gwent']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);

Map.setCenter(1.1, 51.5, 8);
Map.addLayer(filteredArea, {}, 'Regions');

var gfc2018= ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6').clip(filteredArea);

var lossImage = gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).gte(7);
var lossBand = lossImage.and(gfc2018.select(['lossyear']).lte(20));
var zones = lossBand.updateMask(lossBand.neq(0));

// Add the loss layer in red.
Map.addLayer(lossImage.updateMask(lossBand),
            {palette: ['FF0000']}, 'Loss 2007 onwards');

var area_threshold = 300; / about 100 hectares?

// Define whole county as a region
var geom = filteredArea.geometry();

// Convert the zones of the forest loss areas to vectors.
var vectors = zones.addBands(zones).reduceToVectors({
  geometry: geom,
  crs: lossBand.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: true,
  labelProperty: 'zone',
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count()
}).filterMetadata("count","greater_than", area_threshold);

// Make a display image for the vectors, add it to the map.
var display = ee.Image(0).updateMask(0).paint(vectors, '000000', 1);
Map.addLayer(display, {palette: '000000'}, 'vectors');

// Export the FeatureCollection to a CSV file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: vectors,
  description: 'Forest',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to choose an elevation image (e.g. the SRTM), and apply `reduceRegions` with the vectors as input feature collection.

```
var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003"); // exampleelevation image

// add min, max and mean elevation of each geometry
var reducers = ee.Reducer.min()
                .combine(ee.Reducer.max(), '', true)
                .combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), '', true);
vectors = SRTM.reduceRegions(vectors, reducers, 30);
print(vectors)
```

Properties are automatically names 'mean', 'min', and 'max', which is probably fine for your csv file. [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/55a954a23f96679cb148b8b51972ae7a)

Comment: Absolutely superb! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there any way you can change the names too?

Comment: see two examples in the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7213947336cbd4c179775480be9527ae). Note that you will always have to look up how the properties are named, so you carefully rename the right values.

Comment: Fantastic! Feel like I am asking a lot but how could you then add a field from FAO/GAUL/2015/level2 to each shape such as ADM2_CODE?